# jQuery validation success show gif loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, loader

I have using `jQuery` validation plug in for one of my forms. The validation rules are working fine.

But my question is if validation success, after click submit button show gif loader.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to get this to work?

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fullname: {
      required: true
    },
    mobile:{
     required:true,
     minlength: 10,
     number:true
    },
    email:{
     required:true,
     email:true
    }
  },
  messages: {
     fullname: {
         required: "Please enter your name"
     },
     mobile:{
      required: "Please enter your mobile number",
      minlength:"Minumum length 10 digits"
     },
     email:{
      required: "Please enter your email-id",
      email: "Invalid email-id"
     }
 }
});
```

```css
.gif-loader
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif-loader">
<img src="https://www.voya.ie/Interface/Icons/LoadingBasketContents.gif" />
</div>
<form method="POST" id="myform" class="submit" action="insert.php">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname" name="fullname">
 <input type="text" maxlength="10"  title="Enter your 10 digit mobile number" placeholder="Mobile No." name="mobile" id="mobile" >
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" id="email">
 <select name="demo_date" id="demo_date">
  <option value="">Select Demo Date</option>
  <option value="20-03-2018"> 20th Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="21-03-2018"> 21st Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="22-03-2018"> 22nd Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="23-03-2018"> 23rd Mar 2018</option>
 </select>
 <select name="demo_time" id="demo_time">
  <option value="">Select Time</option>
  <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Register here" class="download-button" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/410unv4m/3/)

You need to add submit handler for that...

```
submitHandler: function() { $(".gif-loader").show(); }
```

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fullname: {
      required: true
    },
    mobile:{
     required:true,
     minlength: 10,
     number:true
    },
    email:{
     required:true,
     email:true
    }
  },
  messages: {
     fullname: {
         required: "Please enter your name"
     },
     mobile:{
      required: "Please enter your mobile number",
      minlength:"Minumum length 10 digits"
     },
     email:{
      required: "Please enter your email-id",
      email: "Invalid email-id"
     }
 },
  submitHandler: function() { $(".gif-loader").show(); $('#myform').submit();}
});
```

```css
.gif-loader
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif-loader">
<img src="https://www.voya.ie/Interface/Icons/LoadingBasketContents.gif" />
</div>
<form method="POST" id="myform" class="submit" action="insert.php">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname" name="fullname">
 <input type="text" maxlength="10"  title="Enter your 10 digit mobile number" placeholder="Mobile No." name="mobile" id="mobile" >
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" id="email">
 <select name="demo_date" id="demo_date">
  <option value="">Select Demo Date</option>
  <option value="20-03-2018"> 20th Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="21-03-2018"> 21st Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="22-03-2018"> 22nd Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="23-03-2018"> 23rd Mar 2018</option>
 </select>
 <select name="demo_time" id="demo_time">
  <option value="">Select Time</option>
  <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Register here" class="download-button" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Accept the answer as well.

Comment: Bro one sec submit not working i mean the form not redirect `index.php` page.

Comment: It will redirect to insert.php because you have set the action property as insert.php..

Comment: It okay bro now am using `$('#myform').submit();` in `submitHandler` now its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166785/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-sarvan-kumar).

Comment: it causes Maximum call stack size exceeded error ,  anyone has fix for it

Comment: for those who has stack size exceeded error use like this

 $("#myform").validate({
          submitHandler: function (form) {
              console.log('abcd');
              form.submit();
          }
     });

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the submit event? There's a submitHandler in the plugin

To submit, add `$('#myform').submit()`.

**Edit**;

instead of the submit event I would send it via Ajax, like

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $('.gif-loader').show();

    $.post("insert.php", $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);

        $('.gif-loader').hide();
    });
}
```

However, you may need to change the way `insert.php` works in that case.

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  //this bit is new.
  submitHandler: function() {
     $('.gif-loader').show();
  },
  rules: {
    fullname: {
      required: true
    },
    mobile:{
     required:true,
     minlength: 10,
     number:true
    },
    email:{
     required:true,
     email:true
    }
  },
  messages: {
     fullname: {
         required: "Please enter your name"
     },
     mobile:{
      required: "Please enter your mobile number",
      minlength:"Minumum length 10 digits"
     },
     email:{
      required: "Please enter your email-id",
      email: "Invalid email-id"
     }
 }
});
```

```css
.gif-loader
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif-loader">
<img src="https://www.voya.ie/Interface/Icons/LoadingBasketContents.gif" />
</div>
<form method="POST" id="myform" class="submit" action="insert.php">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullname" name="fullname">
 <input type="text" maxlength="10"  title="Enter your 10 digit mobile number" placeholder="Mobile No." name="mobile" id="mobile" >
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" id="email">
 <select name="demo_date" id="demo_date">
  <option value="">Select Demo Date</option>
  <option value="20-03-2018"> 20th Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="21-03-2018"> 21st Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="22-03-2018"> 22nd Mar 2018</option>
  <option value="23-03-2018"> 23rd Mar 2018</option>
 </select>
 <select name="demo_time" id="demo_time">
  <option value="">Select Time</option>
  <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
  <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Register here" class="download-button" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Loader showing but form not redirecting  insert.php. It mean action not working

Comment: @RameshS You'll need to add `$('#myform').submit()` in the handler to make it do stuff.

Comment: @RameshS Having said that, because it actually *redirects* the loader will disappear again since you're loading a new page. You might want to do the submit via ajax or something.

Comment: thanks bro i have added `submitHandler: function() {
     $('.gif-loader').show();
     $('#myform').submit();
  }` now its working